# Docker: no connection between postgres with node

Tags: postgresql, docker, typeorm

I am trying to connect a postgres DB  with Node api, with docker compose like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: biobox
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
  api:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    command: yarn dev:server
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
```

**env**

```
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE=biobox
DATABASE_HOST=db
DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.16.2-alpine

COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .

COPY .env .

EXPOSE 3333
```

My api and db are online on container and the logs show no error.

***because when i try make a query return this:***

```
Using ts-node version 8.8.2, typescript version 3.8.3
api_1  | Create a new user User {
api_1  |   completName: 'Name',
api_1  |   email: 'Name@gmail.com',
api_1  |   cpf: '23425',
api_1  |   dateNasc: '10/10/2020',
api_1  |   number: 'Namefd222',
api_1  |   password: '1Name5234'
api_1  | }
db_1   | 2020-05-31 16:37:00.199 UTC [74] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
```

I don't understand why this happens. My environment variables are in accordance with the docker-compose create, in this case the database, USER, PASS.

Comment: Can you share how is your connection string being mounted by your application?

Comment: In index.ts i creat orm Connection  await createConnection(); from typeorm

in ormconfig i instance env values

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code? full code. Here in the comments is bad to see.

Comment: I would suggest you to connect to your mysql container using any tool like `workbench` or `dbeaver`. If db connection is made then there is something wrong with db configs in your application. If connection is not made then there is something wrong with the docker-compose file. Maybe after that try posting question again.

Comment: Guys, I decided to use a web instance of my database for production, in which case it will not be necessary to use it in the docker.
anyway, thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this issue and found the problem with `alpine`. Even using node 20.10 LTS doesn't help. Just don't use `alpine` node and it will work properly